# Should self-plagiarism tag be renamed to duplicate-publication tag?

Tags: discussion, retagging

This is a tag that was introduced quite recently. Although the term seems to be quite accepted today, a few experts (one of which is an editor of an IEEE transaction journal) claim that is more of a misnomer.

Plagiarism generally means stealing the written work of another by copying it in your publishable work without necessary attribution of the source. But re-publishing your own work cannot be referred to as *stealing*. This can be recalled as double-publication or content-recycling. However due to widely used literature, the word 'self-plagiarism' do refer to double-publication.

Should we continue to keep the tag as it is or rename it to duplicate-publication and make any references to self-plagiarism suggest double-publication instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the same thing. Self-plagiarism also includes reusing your own work outside the context of publication. (For example, in [coursework](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36847/is-it-considered-plagiarism-if-i-use-my-own-answers-twice), or [grant proposals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24009/re-using-text-from-a-grant-proposal-in-a-paper-or-vice-versa).) Self-plagiarism can include re-use of a small bit of content (such as a [methodology section](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24554/overlapping-sentences-in-methodology-descriptions-in-separate-journal-articles)) in essentially different papers, while duplicate publication refers to trying to publish the same paper twice (in its entirety.)

Misnomer or not, self-plagiarism is the most commonly used term for this practice. We generally try to use commonly accepted terms for things as tags.

Comment: I agree. I would strongly suggest to synonymise [double-publication] to [self-plagiarism] though.

Comment: I agree with this - they're similar, but no so similar that they're synonyms.